# accessing remote file using python with different credentials - errno 13 [Permission denied]

Tags: python, remote-access

I am a beginner using python and for the project I'm working on I need some help with this code:

```
    lines = open("\\\\oj-public\\hi.log","r")
```

with prompts an errno 13: [Permission denied] error

I'm trying to access multiple log files that are present in many different remote servers.
The code I'm running I want to run from my server and I'm not admin on any of the remote.
So, because I want my code to be easily scalable and to run from many different users in the future..
Is there a way to access the remote files with different credentials (assuming I know the users and passwords of the admins to each of the servers)?

Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: you can not use wildcards in `open`. and the syntax has no `.` (after `open` - before the opening bracket).

Comment: I just didn't to bore you with the details of the servername and path.. it's just a template for a real valid path. And oops, you're right about the '.'. It's a mistake. But sill.. about my question..